# Normalising counted values by group

Tags: pandas

I have a table of data in which companies have differing numbers of locations with different values for each key.

| Key | Company | Value | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Start | Burgers | Monday | Sydney |
| Start | Burgers | Sunday | Brisbane |
| Start | Donuts | Monday | Sydney |

I want to count the different values but normalised so that companies with multiple locations don't skew things. The output i'm hoping for is something like this:

| Value | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 1.5 |
| Sunday | 0.5 |

Keep banging my head against how to approach this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is it that `Monday` is `1.5` in the output?

Comment: Burgers has two locations so Monday is 50% of it's values, whereas Donuts has one location making Monday 100% of it's values